# Raspberry Pi Model 3 Overclocking Settings?

Tags: pi-3, overclocking

I have procured a Raspberry Pi Model 3 few days ago and planning to (safely!) overclock it. I want to get maximum from my little Pi 3 and looking for the instructions for the safe overclocking. I am also planning to install heat sink on the pi. I tried searching internet and stackoverflow for the detailed instructions. However, I could not find satisfactory step-by-step guide for safe overclocking of Pi3.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=138123

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=138840

http://www.jackenhack.com/raspberry-pi-3-overclocking/

http://hackaday.com/2016/03/03/overclocking-the-raspberry-pi-3-for-tasty-speed-increases/

https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/Overclocking

[Raspberry Pi Model B 3 Overclocking?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43303/raspberry-pi-model-b-3-overclocking)

Comment: Overclocking is not safe in first place Ashwin. Read https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/Overclocking this seriously and think again before overclocking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Overclock at your own risk:**

Overclocking is not exactly safe, but it can be done right and the Pi 3 will likely run without any problems if so. Not all Pi's are made equal so some people may be able to overclock their Pi to 1500 MHz will others may only be able to get 1300 MHz. It is a game of testing. I have my Pi 3 running perfectly fine at `arm_freq=1350` MHz with the `sdram_freq=550` and `over_voltage=6`.

To overclock your Pi 3 open the `/boot/config.txt` file and test different things. Maybe first try `arm_freq=1250` and then put your Pi 3 under a heavy load and see how it works. To find the right numbers you will need to test different things. If the Pi starts to freeze, changing the `over_voltage` settings may be necessary, but do so at your own risk. If the Pi refuses to boot at some point, just put the sd card in your laptop, open the `/boot/config.txt` file on your laptop, and change the numbers to something more modest.

**Again, overclock at your own risk.**

Comment: confirmed, got mine to work fine by editing /boot/config.txt to the settings you mention above, `arm_freq=1350` `sdram_freq=550` and `over_voltage=6`