# Pi 3 GPU overclocking ability

Tags: pi-3, gpu, overclocking

As far as I am aware the Pi 3's CPU is currently not overclockable, its maximum clock speed is set at 1.2GHz.

But what about overclocking the GPU? Is it even possible? And would I see performance gains in applications like playing games?

Comment: Possible duplicate or just related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/43303/24224. Basically, even the CPU is overclockable. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to overclock the GPU and yes , this leads to a performance improvement.

Look at following resources:

- Official overclocking overview [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#overclocking)
- example config.txt settings [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=138123#p938055).

Please don't forget that **overclocking is a gamble** , your Pi might not be overclockable , crash and corrupt SD cards.

**Active cooling** is highly advisable while overclocking the Pi3 :

[image: picture of heat distribution on a RPi3]